# Showing equivalence relations a=b/a=-b

Tags: equivalence-relations

I have this equivalence relation where $S=\mathbb{R}$ and $a\sim b$
$ \iff a=b$ or $a=-b$

I know this is an equivalence relation and that it is also very simple but I am just confused about how to test for reflectivity, symmetry and transitivity? Like how can I see what $a\sim a$ actually means? Like do I check that subbing $a$ as $b$ it still works or? But surely this would mean $a=-a$ ?

Sorry for the confusion but if anyone has the time to offer some insight I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: $a=a$ is true, $a=-a$ is false, so $a=a$ or $a=-a$ is true so $a\sim a$

Comment: It is sufficient when $a=b$ OR $a=-b$ holds. Hence $a=a$ actually shows the reflexivity.

Comment: Oh I see I completely disregarded "OR"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Like how can I see what $a\sim a$ actually means?

$a\sim a$ is a *statement*. A statement can be either *true* or *false*. What that statement is is defined by what $\sim$ means, and in your case, for any arbitrary $a,b$, the statement "$a\sim b$" is the same as the statement "$a=b$ or $a=-b$. Therefore, the statement $a\sim a$ is the statement $a=a$ **or** $a=-a$.

Notice that there is an **or**, not an **and**, connecting the two substatements, one being $a=a$ and the other $a=-a$.

In order for a statement $A$ **or** $B$ to be true, only **one** of the statements $A$, $B$ needs to be true. So, following from this, we see that $a\sim a$ is a true statement if **one** of the statements "$a=a$", "$a=-a$" is true. Clearly, one of them ($a=a$) **is** true, and therefore, $a\sim a $ is also true. Regardless of whether the other, $a=-a$, is true or not.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps!